# Find a element by title with puppeteer js

Tags: javascript, node.js, puppeteer

Using puppeteer js I loop over all elements like so:

```
  const getAllElements = await page.$$('._1Nk0C');

  for (let [i, link] of getAllElements.entries()) {
      await link.hover();
      await link.screenshot({path: `example${i}.png`});
  }
```

Inside of the element there's another element which is an  with a title of "download".  Like so:

```
<a title="Download photo" href="https://example.com/df.jpg/download?force=true" rel="nofollow" download="" target="_blank" class="_1QwHQ"></a>
```

I need to get that element so I can click on it.
I tried this:

```
  for (let [i, link] of getAllElements.entries()) {
      await link.hover();
      await link.screenshot({path: `example${i}.png`});
      const download = await page.evaluate(() => [...document.querySelector('a[title="Download photo"]')])
      console.log(download);
  }
```

This gave me an error:

```
UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error: Evaluation failed: TypeError: document.querySelector is not a function or its return value is not iterable
```

How can I do it to get that element?

Comment: If you open DevTools and paste `[...document.querySelector('a[title="Download photo"]')]` in the console, you will get that error. Why do you want to return an array?

Comment: I don't want to get an array just that single element.  I thought querySelector would find the one in the block I'm in.  @hardkoded

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can call `$` on your `link` variable:

```js
let linkPhoto = await link.$('a[title="Download photo"]');
```